# "Pertubation" of an optimization method

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Assuming we have a optimization method with convergence properties such as $\nabla f(x_k) \to 0$ for minimizing $f$ (or at least a subsequence or whatever, not important for me). I need to modify the method such that after every iteration, a "random" move is made that only guarantees $$f(x_{k+1}) \leq f(x_k)$$ but no further conditions for this update.

What kind of conditions on the optimization method do I need so that I don't destroy the convergence properties? Is there any literature about that?

Comment: Do you want to add a "noise" term to gradient descent?  Please clarify.

Comment: In this generality, I don't know of any reference for this. One buzzword maybe "monotone methods", but I am note sure if this actually works. There are monotone versions of some methods that are not descent methods per se, but I don't know of a general principle.

Comment: I don't want to add a noise term to the gradient, just a "random" step after iteration that only guarantees that the objective does not increase but no further assumptions.

Comment: Thank you, do you know of specific optimization methods where this kind of pertubation does not destroy the convergence?

Comment: That looks like noise to me, just noise that goes "down" rather than "up".